# Why do I need to include a withApollo HOC on a component to satisfy the TypeScript compiler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using React, Typescript, and Apollo in an application. I have an arbitrary React component that I'd like to render. The component uses the `compose` function to handle loading data from a series of graphql queries.

parent.tsx

```
<MyComponent />
```

myComponent.tsx

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
   // code, render, etc
    export default compose(
         graphql(queryGetSomeData, { name: "GetSomeData" }...
```

When I don't include any props with the component, everything is fine, the Typescript compiler doesn't complain, and the app renders. The moment I try to include a prop (of any kind), the compiler complains in the following manner:

```
<MyComponent doSomething={this.doSomeFunction} /> // or foo, or foo={'bar'}
```

`[ts] Property 'doSomething' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ childr...'.
(property) Parent.doSomething: () => aReturnType`

When I add the `withApollo` HOC to the `compose` function of MyComponent, the error goes away and the compiler runs successfully.

```
export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(queryGetSomeData, { name: "GetSomeData" }...
```

I've read through the [withApollo docs](https://github.com/apollographql/react-docs/blob/master/source/api.md#withApollo) and generally understand that withApollo provides access to the Apollo client. However, none of my other components have this limitation, and I'm struggling to understand a) why this component is different and requires withApollo and b) how withApollo solves this particular problem.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is compose here ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge--compose is a redux method (import { compose } from "redux") that allows you to wrap a component in several HOCs in a row. https://redux.js.org/api-reference/compose